# enable or disable the checkboxlist item using jquery

Tags: jquery, struts2, checkboxlist

I've a checkboxlist for setting 'Status' as `<s:checkboxlist list="{'Enabled','Disabled'}" name="processVO.status"/>` . So when I check any one from this list, the other one should be disabled. I tried many ways, but not working. Pls help.
Thanks

Comment: How about using Radio buttons instead? As you can select only one of the options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my answer. little bit length. But works

```
<s:checkboxlist list="checkboxListIs" label="Day"  name="checkedItems" id="checkBox" onchange="return Ischecked(this);"></s:checkboxlist>
```

javascript code

```
function Ischecked(current){
    if( $(current).is(":checked")){
        var name = current.name;
        var id = current.id;
        var substr = id.split('-');
        var num = substr[1];
        if(num==1){
        num = 2;
        }else{
         num = 1;   
        }
        $("#"+name+"-"+num).attr("disabled","disabled");

     }
}
```

I think it will help u. Modify the above based on your requirement.
The struts framesworks assigns the id for checkbox. (id = **name-"list object positon**")

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
   $('input:checkbox').click(function() { 
     if ($(this).is(':checked')) { 
       $('input:text').val('').attr('disabled', true); 
     } else { 
       $('input:text').attr('disabled', false); 
     } 
   }); 
});
```

Comment: @rutwik reddy : We've given the UI design as checkboxlist to be used. That's why preferring it most :)

Comment: some of modification of above code its may be help you try on that.. according to your logic.

Comment: @ Dilip Godhani : I've a checkboxlist as I mentioned above in my Qn. So If I check 'Enabled' checkbox, the 'Disabled' checkbox should go disable and the converse is also true. I used the code as You mentioned above. But still it's not working for me

Comment: This is the code for checkboxlist I'm using <s:checkboxlist list="{'Enabled','Disabled'}" name="processVO.status" /> . In the case of normal checkbox I'm able to do the operation, but in the case of checkboxlist it's not working